# Constants best practices

Tags: c#, dictionary, constants

I have a simple classes which are initialized with dictionary values and can return its values as dictionary, here is an example:

```
public class ApartmentModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public ApartmentModel()
    {
    }

    public ApartmentModel(IDictionary<string, object> item)
    {
        Id = (int)item["ID"];
        Title = item["Title"].ToString();           
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, object> FieldsValues()
    {
        var item = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["ID"] = Id,
            ["Title"] = Title                
        };
        return item;
    }
}
```

Some classes have common fields, like "Id" and "Title".
I'm wondering what is the best practice to store dictionary keys strings as constants: in the same class as private fields or in the settings/resource file?

Comment: Depends on how often your kexs change. If this happens only when releasing new software feel free to hardcode it into your code. However put it into any konfig-file when you plan to create or delete new keys quite often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the values of your constants correspond to property names. In situations like that it is best not to use string literals at all, replacing with `nameof` operator (assuming that C# 6 language is in use)

```
public ApartmentModel(IDictionary<string, object> item)
{
    Id = (int)item[nameof(Id)];
    Title = item[nameof(Title)].ToString();           
}

public override IDictionary<string, object> FieldsValues()
{
    var item = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        [nameof(Id)] = Id,
        [nameof(Title)] = Title                
    };
    return item;
}
```

An even better approach is to not code these methods directly, replacing them with a single method based on reflection and custom attributes. Define an attribute that designates a property for inclusion in `FieldsValues` - generated `IDIctionary`, and write a single helper method that walks your object's class hierarchy, finds all attributes with the custom attribute, and produces / consumes a dictionary based on them.

Comment: Do you mean to create some sort of static class with a helper method, and call it in FieldsValues to produce IDictionaty?

Comment: @AlexanderSmith Correct, that's the approach I would take.